# Efficiently capture variable number of patterns with Julia regex?

Tags: regex, julia

I am pulling a data out of giant text files where the sections I am interested in look like

```
...
section:NumberOfSurvivorsPerVault
subsection:1958
xy:1_1034
xy:2_2334
subsection:1959
xy:1_1334
xy:2_2874
xy:7_12
...
section:MeanCapsPerGhoul
subsection:1962
xy:1_234
xy:2_121
....
```

The sections/subsections are randomly scattered throughout the text file and have variable numbers of xy pairs.  Right now I am readall'ing the full text and capturing each and adding them to a dataframe with:

```
function pushparametricdata(df, full) 
    for m = eachmatch(r"section:(.*)\r\nsubsection:([0-9]*)\r\n((xy:[0-9]*_.*?\r\n)+)"m, full)
        for r = eachmatch(r"xy:([0-9]+)_(.*?)\r\n"m, m.captures[3])
            push!(df, [m.captures[1], int(m.captures[2]), int(r.captures[1]), float(r.captures[2])])
        end
    end
end
```

This works OK, but I think this allocates at least twice as much memory as it needs to due to the two regexes, and @time shows that 80% of the run is gc.  Is there any way this can be done without making an intermediate copy?  (From what I can tell it's not possible to do it with a single regex).

Comment: You could try to use only [`(?m)(?:^|\G)xy:([0-9]+)_(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/nN9tB5/2): `function pushparametricdata(df, full) 
    for m = eachmatch(r"(?m)(?:^|\G)xy:([0-9]+)_(.*)"m, full)
        push!(df, [m.captures[1], int(m.captures[2]), int(r.captures[1]), float(r.captures[2])])
    end
end`. Here is [a demo showing what I mean](http://goo.gl/EMe3lj).

Comment: Good thought, but I'm afraid I have many different sections and each one has various numbers of xy pairs and subsections.

Comment: Ok, what about optimizing the first regex then? Try [`(?s)section:(.*?)subsection:([0-9]+)\s+((?:xy:[0-9]*_[^\n]+\r?\n)+)`](https://regex101.com/r/nN9tB5/5). The second regex can be `xy:([0-9]+)_([^\n]*)`.

Comment: Ah nice!  I forgot about non-capturing groups, that will actually cut the memory usage by a decent amount since the actual prefix I'm looking for is not xy: but something way longer. Let me see how much that speeds it up.

Comment: You might be doing an overkill using regexes. Why not use[`split(line,":")`](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/strings/#Base.split)?

Comment: I'm afraid I had to simplify the sample data above -- I'm actually matching a string which contains several copies of the deliminator on the inner loop.  I'll give it a shot though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what you need to validate on the rest of the text file.
For instance, if you don't need syntax validation, as in you know for sure that the text file has a correct section-subsection-item structure, you could use this RegEx:

```
(?:\G|(?:\G|^section:(.*)[\r\n]+)subsection:(\d*)[\r\n]+)xy:(\d*_.*+[\r\n]+)
```

iterating for each *xy pair*.

---

Example:

```
for m = eachmatch(r"(?:\G|(?:\G|^section:(.*)[\r\n]+)subsection:(\d*)[\r\n]+)xy:(\d*_.*+[\r\n]+)"m, full)
    if m.captures[2] != nothing
        sub = m.captures[2]
        if m.captures[1] != nothing
            sec = m.captures[1]
        end
    end
    item = m.captures[3]

    print("SECTION: ", sec, " -- SUBSECTION: ", sub, " -- ITEM: ", item)
end
```

**Please forgive me, this is the first time I try coding in Julia.*

Prints:

```
SECTION: NumberOfSurvivorsPerVault -- SUBSECTION: 1958 -- ITEM: 1_1034
SECTION: NumberOfSurvivorsPerVault -- SUBSECTION: 1958 -- ITEM: 2_2334
SECTION: NumberOfSurvivorsPerVault -- SUBSECTION: 1959 -- ITEM: 1_1334
SECTION: NumberOfSurvivorsPerVault -- SUBSECTION: 1959 -- ITEM: 2_2874
SECTION: NumberOfSurvivorsPerVault -- SUBSECTION: 1959 -- ITEM: 7_12
SECTION: MeanCapsPerGhoul -- SUBSECTION: 1962 -- ITEM: 1_234
SECTION: MeanCapsPerGhoul -- SUBSECTION: 1962 -- ITEM: 2_121
```

---

This expression uses `\G` to match at the end of last match. So it will try to match in this order:

1. If there was a previous match, try to match the *xy pair* in `m.captures[3]` anchored to the end of last match, leaving the 1st and 2nd capturing group unset.
2. If (1) doesn't match, try to match both the *subsection* and the *xy pair* in `m.captures[2]` and `m.captures[3]`, again anchored to the end of last match, leaving the 1st capturing group unset.
3. Try to perform a full match, with *section*, *subsection* and the *xy pair*

This example will work on your subject text, and only serves as a starting point to a working example depending on the actual structure of your text files. Take into account that it will fail if you have subsections missing for example.